# Changing month_id when looping over dates in python

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary of dates where I have an id for each day, and a month id for each day in a specific month. Like:

| id | month_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-02 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-01-03 |
| ... | ... | .... |
| 32 | 2 | 2021-02-01 |
| 33 | 2 | 2021-02-02 |

...

I have the following code so far:

```
def create_date_table():
    d1 = date(2021, 1, 1)
    d2 = date(2022, 12, 31)
    delta = d2 - d1
    dates = []
    date_id = 1
    month_id = 1
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        full_date = (d1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        dates.append({'id': date_id,
                      'month_id': month_id,
                     'date': full_date})
        date_id+=1
        #increase the month_id here when month changes
    print(dates)
```

I am not sure how to check when a month changes in the for loop. It is important that 2022 January's month_id should be 13, not 1 again. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if I understand, the issue is only the `month_id`? Which will reset to one every time you call  `create_date_table` but obviously you want to keep count correct?

Comment: no, the date_id is totally ok, i want a separate id for each day. The issue is the month_id, I am not sure how to tell python to only increase the month_id when the month changes. Like for all January dates it should be 1, all February dates it should be 2 and so on. What makes it hard for me is that I want to keep it increasing when a year ends. So it should be 13 in 2022 January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the month and if it changes increase the month_id as below

```
def create_date_table():
    d1 = date(2021, 1, 1)
    d2 = date(2022, 12, 31)
    delta = d2 - d1
    dates = []
    date_id = 1
    month_id = 1
    last_month = d1.month
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        new_date = (d1 + timedelta(days=i))
        full_date = new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        dates.append({'id': date_id,
                      'month_id': month_id,
                     'date': full_date})
        date_id+=1
        #increase the month_id here when month changes
        if last_month != new_date.month:
            last_month = new_date.month
            month_id+=1
    print(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stateless Closure:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def create_date_table():
    d1 = date(2021, 1, 1)
    d2 = date(2022, 12, 31)
    delta = d2 - d1
    dates = []
    date_id = 1
    month_id = 1
    month_counter = 1 # This resets at every time the month changes
    
    def month_cal(month_):  # Closure
        nonlocal month_id
        nonlocal month_counter
        month_ = int(month_)       
        month_id += 1
        month_counter = month_  


    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
       
        full_date = (d1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        current_month = full_date.split('-')[1] # Grab Month
        if int(current_month) != month_counter:
            month_cal(current_month)
    
        dates.append({'id': date_id,
                      'month_id': month_id,
                     'date': full_date})
        date_id+=1
        
    print(dates)

create_date_table()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Save the first value of the month you want to start with(`last_month` variable).
- In the loop, take the month value of `full_date` then compare this with `last_month`. If it changes, increase `month_id`.

  ```
  def create_date_table():
        d1 = date(2021, 1, 1)
        d2 = date(2022, 12, 31)
        delta = d2 - d1
        dates = []
        date_id = 1
        month_id = 1
        last_month = int(d1.month) # assigns the first month value to last_month variable
        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            full_date = (d1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            month = int(full_date.split('-')[1]) # split full_date to ['year', 'month', 'day'] then take month value
            if month-last_month != 0: # if month changes
                month_id += 1 # increase month_id
                last_month = month # reset last_month
            dates.append({'id': date_id,
                          'month_id': month_id,
                         'date': full_date})
            date_id+=1
        print(dates)
  ```